# Receive XMLA from ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, xmla

I have a ruby server side program that uses a specific library to send request to an olap server and receives the result dataset from the same library.

For some reason, I don't want to call the library methods for receiving result dataset and I want to receive the text XMLA result directly. But I don't know what is the code in ruby (or jruby?) to do this. I want to send a query and receive the 'text' XMLA from my rest service(which is in ruby)

Answer (score 2):

Hey I see this is a bit old, but still. As far as I could tell you have two choices:

1. Use https://github.com/rsim/mondrian-olap - all kinds off cool stuff, but requires jruby since it uses java libraries for connecting and manipulating the cube itself
2. Use https://github.com/drKreso/cube - barebone as it gets, but you can connect to the Mondrian XML servlet via savon SOAP messages and get the data back. Good for educational purposes since it has the message needed (if you want to port to python it would be a breeze)

p.s. I made the choice 2) so I might be somewhat biased :)